# Meaning/usage of "it's not that bad"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, american-english

What do people mean when they say:

> "I don't think it was **that bad**."

Does this phrase have only one possible correct meaning or use? Does it require further context to be provided in order to understand it?

Answer (score 3):

On its own

> I don't think it was that bad.

is a generally unenthusiastic comment on something, such as

- It was not very good.
- I almost liked it.
- It was reasonable.

However, if someone has just made a remark, then the phrase is a reply in context:

> I thought the food was disgusting.
>   It wasn't that bad.

meaning, "I don't think it was as bad as you are saying."